# Weird issue of SVN repository Path in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: svn, eclipse-juno

I have installed [Eclipse update site URL:](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x)

Now when i am trying import project from SVN Server

> (Path:- svn://srv-svn/myProject/trunk/workspace)

in Eclipse Juno i am getting weird repository location you can see attached screen shot
[image: Screenshot]

So i am not able to login .
Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: Anyone have any idea here?

Comment: Issue resolved user credential changed by Admin